# How to fetch an object of a nested Factory in RSPEC/FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I create two models at the same time trough a nested Form and want to test the functionality with this factory:

```
factory :company do
  name "ACME"
  after(:build) do |company|
    company.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, company: company)       
  end       
end

factory :user do
  first_name     "Foo"
  last_name      "Bar"
  email          "foo@bar.com"
  password       "foobar"
  password_confirmation "foobar"
  company  
end
```

Now I create a company in RSPEC like

```
let(:company) { FactoryGirl.create(:company) }
```

and have a test like

```
it { should have_title(user.first_name) }
```

where i want to fetch the user's fisrt name from the user's model. Right now I can only access the Company's model in RSPEC.

How can I fetch the attributes of the user's model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to create user but you only build so without save:

```
company.users << FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

or

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, company: company)
```

next you can have access to user first name for example by(if company has_many :users):

```
it { should have_title(company.users.first.first_name) }
```